# How is Reddit a news aggregator?

Tags: rss, reddit, rss-reader

I read that Reddit is a news aggregator; if that’s the case, does it support RSS feeds and can I add my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reddit generates a RSS feed for every subreddit.

For r/aww the feed is available at https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.rss

You can also combine feeds:
https://www.reddit.com/r/aww+firefox/.rss

Inline-reddit.com offers better image feeds for Reddit. For r/aww the URL is http://inline-reddit.com/feed/?subreddit=aww

Or you can sort by hot, new, controversial:

- http://inline-reddit.com/feed/?subreddit=AskReddit/top
- http://inline-reddit.com/feed/?subreddit=AskReddit/hot
- http://inline-reddit.com/feed/?subreddit=AskReddit/controversial